# C# Threading Запустить метод из потока UI

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Как запустить метод с UI потока?
У меня есть статичный класс Log для вывода сообщений в лог со всех частей программы.
Выглядит так:

```
static class Log
{
    static private ListBox _loglistbox;
    public static void initialize(ListBox loglistbox)
    {
        _loglistbox = loglistbox;
    }
    public static void addComment(string comment)
    {
        _loglistbox.Items.Add(comment);
        _loglistbox.SelectedIndex = _loglistbox.Items.Count - 1;
        _loglistbox.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }
}
```

При старте я передаю туда в какой listbox писать и он исправно выполняет обязанности.
Начал переводить свой основной метод в поток, чтобы не тормозил интерфейс при выполнении. С потока когда обращаюсь к классу Log получаю ошибку обращения с другого потока, подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно обратиться с другого потока к классу Log, чтобы он смогу вывести сообщение в listbox?

```
        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread writeDataThread = new Thread(writeDataToBase);            
        writeDataThread.Start(); 
    }            
        private void writeDataToBase()
    {
        Log.addComment("Start"); // ошибка
    }
```

Comment: Win Forms, WPF?

Comment: WinForms совсем забыл указать

Answer (score 2):

```
public static void addComment(string comment)
{
    _loglistbox.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => 
    {
        _loglistbox.Items.Add(comment);
        _loglistbox.SelectedIndex = _loglistbox.Items.Count - 1;
        _loglistbox.SelectedIndex = -1; 
    }));
}
```

Comment: А где обращение к статическому классу?Как оно будет работать?

Comment: @RomanIeromenko не понял вопроса... К какому статическому классу и зачем?

Comment: @RomanIeromenko это валидное решение для WPF (там у всех контролов есть свойство Dispatcher). У вас - решение для Winforms.

Comment: Спасибо, буду знать

Answer (score 1):

У меня другое решение без класса закрытого Dispatcher, во-первых я бы добавил свойство  для  _loglistbox:

```
 static class Log
{
    static private ListBox _loglistbox;
    **static public ListBox Loglistbox { get { return _loglistbox; } }**
    public static void initialize(ListBox loglistbox)
    {
        _loglistbox = loglistbox;
    }
    public static void addComment(string comment)
    {
        _loglistbox.Items.Add(comment);
        _loglistbox.SelectedIndex = _loglistbox.Items.Count - 1;
        _loglistbox.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }       
}
```

Ну а сама реализация такова, кстати упустили, откуда берется внутренняя статическая переменная класса ListBox

```
 private void writeDataToBase()
    {                      
        BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)
                    (() =>
                    {
                        **Log.initialize(new ListBox());**
                        Log.addComment("Bla Bla Bla");
                    }
                    ));
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, решил подобным образом:`if (_loglistbox.InvokeRequired) _loglistbox.Invoke(new Action<string>((s) =>
            {
                _loglistbox.Items.Add(s);
            }), comment);`